Проблема с выводом парсера на Python
Проблема вот в чём, есть парсер он должен находить все объявления по запросу, к примеру запрос будет геймпад после запроса он должен выдать ссылки на страницы в авито. В нём вроде нет ошибок но при запуске скрипта он ничего не выводит.
Это выглядит так:
Что хотели найти:
геймпад
Process finished with exit code 0
Ина этом заканчивается весь код.
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    
    product = input("Что хотели найти:")
    url = "https://www.avito.ru/krasnodar?q=" + product
    
    requests = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(requests.text, "html.parser")
    all_links = bs.find_all("a", class_="styles-module-root-YeOVk styles-module-root_noVisited-MpiGq")
    
    for link in all_links:
        print("https://www.avito.ru/" + link["href"])


Авито против, сначала договоритесь...

аххаха, а если серьёзна то реально авито блокает парсеры?
